# Why does my AJAX loading fail the first time through when hosting my MVC3 project in IIS7?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I was writing an mvc application with a few tabs. I noted that when hosted on IIS 7, the home page has a link triggering a JavaScript function to load content via AJAX.

It doesn't work on the first page load, however when I visit some other tab and come back to the home page and click on the link it works perfectly. Can someone tell me the reason for this or how to avoid it?

#### The Loading Code

```
function GetLabels(project) {
    var xmlHttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("light").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "/Home/GetLabels?project="+project, true);
    xmlHttp.send();
    document.getElementById('light').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("light").innerHTML = 
       "<img src='Content/load.gif' alt='Please wait' />";
}
```

#### The Link that Triggers it

```
Click <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="GetLabels('A')">here</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not hardcode urls like this:

```
xmlHttp.open("GET", "/Home/GetLabels?project="+project, true);
```

You should always use url helpers to generate them:

```
xmlHttp.open("GET", "@Url.Action("GetLabels", "Home")?project=" + encodeURIComponent(project), true);
```

Now your AJAX request will work no matter whether you are hosting in Visual Studio's built-in server or IIS. The reason why your code doesn't work in IIS is because in IIS your application is hosted ni a virtual directory that you must include in your url. So the correct url is not `/home/getlabels` but `/appname/home/getlabels` which is something that the url helper takes into account.

Also since you are using a GET request the web browser might cache the result and never send a request again to the server. To avoid this you should append a random query string parameter to the url or use the POST verb.

Comment: Or use `cache: false`